# How can I merge two arrays recursively for only keys in the first array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am trying to merge two arrays recursively while following some simple rules:
1) Get the values from the second array for only keys which exist in the first array, and whose value isn't another array.
2) The keys in the first array which don't have a matching key in the second array should be set to zero.

Array1

```
Array
(
    [a_arr] => Array
    (
        [u1] => Array
        (
            [v] => 
            [a] => 
            [e] => 
            [d] => 
        )
        [u2] => Array
        (
            [v] => 
            [a] => 
            [e] => 
            [d] => 
        )
    )
    [b_arr] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [a_arr] => Array
    (
        [u1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [e] => 1
        )
        [u2] => Array
        (
            [v] => 1 
        )
        [u3] => Array
        (
            [e] => 1 
        )
    )
    [b_arr] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Expected output array after merging:

```
Array
(
    [a_arr] => Array
    (
        [u1] => Array
        (
            [v] => 0
            [a] => 1
            [e] => 1
            [d] => 0
        )
        [u2] => Array
        (
            [v] => 1
            [a] => 0
            [e] => 0
            [d] => 0
        )
    )
    [b_arr] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

The function I wrote to do this is:

```
private function mergeArrayRecursive(&$arr1,&$arr2){
        foreach($arr1 AS $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                if(isset($arr2[$k])){
                    $this->mergeArrayRecursive($v,$arr2[$k]);
                }
            }
            else if(isset($arr2[$k])){
                $arr1[$k] = $arr2[$k];
            }
            else{
                $arr1[$k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work and the array seems to remain unaffected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following method:

```
private function mergeArrayRecursive($arr1, $arr2){
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v) && isset($arr2[$k])) {
            $arr1[$k] = $this->mergeArrayRecursive($v, $arr2[$k]);
        } else if (isset($arr2[$k])) {
            $arr1[$k] = $arr2[$k];
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```

What's changed ? There is no last `else` statement and you have forget about `return`. Also params does not have `&` reference.

Comment: That partially works, but still the elements in array1 which are not set by the second array, need to be set to `0`, with this, they still remain empty.

Comment: @user279988 If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the thick on the left.